# Modificar archivo en directorio resources en Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Hola estoy haciendo un proyecto en visual studio 2015 y tengo un PictureBox cuya imagen se coge de la carpeta Resources. Esa imagen la necesitare cambiar todos los dias estoy intentado cambiar la imagen a mano sustituyendola en el directorio, pero luego al ejecutar la aplicacion muestra la antigua.

Alguien sabe si es posible lo que estoy intentando?
Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. si lo guardaste como un recurso embebido en la aplicacion no. 
Deberias cargarlo directamente desde la carpeta necesaria para poder hacer lo que quieres.

Comment: Gracias por la info, ya lo he solucionado de otra manera.

Comment: @Sergio: Si has solucionado tu problema de otra manera, sería considerado de tu parte el que agregues tu solución como una respuesta a tu pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

Al final lo solucione leyendo el archivo desde una ruta (que como en mi aplicacio no cambia me sirve esta solucion) con File.Readallbytes

```
byte[] ImageByte =  File.ReadAllBytes(Application.StartupPath + "/bote.jpg");
MemoryStream MemStream = new MemoryStream(ImageByte);
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(MemStream);
```

Answer (score 1):

Has intentado cargar la imagen desde un archivo de la siguiente forma:

```
    string ImagesDirectory = 
        Path.Combine(
            Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),
            "imagenes"
        );
   string rutaImagen = Path.Combine(ImagesDirectory, "nombreArchivo.png");
   pictureBox1.image = =Image.FromFile(rutaImagen);
```